# Update ListView Adapter input with radioButtons

Tags: java, android

My app fetches data from a server and shows it in a listView. I’m sorting the data and want to show them as well so I thought to use radioButtons to change the view. With every button another content should be loaded into the List which the adapter shows. The problem is that no view comes up, my screen stays blank unfortunately. How do I load them correctly and change the input onClick? (In this case I want to show contactList and contactListTwo with the radioButtons)

That‘s my code so far. The part that I spoke about is at the bottom:

```
public class CallsFragment extends Fragment{

private String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
private ListView lv;
private static String url = "xx";
int a = 1;
String title;
private BaseAdapter mContactsAdapter;
private RadioGroup rg;
RadioButton rb1;
RadioButton rb2;
RadioButton rb3;
private final List<HashMap<String, String>> mContactsListItems = new ArrayList<>();

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactListTwo;

private static final int rb1id = 2;
private static final int rb2id = 1;
private static final int rb3id = 0;

public CallsFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_calls, container, false);

    contactList = new ArrayList<>();
    contactListTwo = new ArrayList<>();

    rg = (RadioGroup) view.findViewById(R.id.RGroup);
    rb1 = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.radioButton5);
    rb2 = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.radioButton4);
    rb3 = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.radioButton6);

    rb1.setId(rb1id);
    rb2.setId(rb2id);
    rb3.setId(rb3id);

    ((ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list))
            .setAdapter(mContactsAdapter);

    return view;
}


private class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute () {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground (Void...arg0){
        HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();

        //request to url and getting response
        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall("https://creativecommons.tankerkoenig.de/json/list.php?lat=" + lat + "&lng=" + lon + "&rad=" + umkreis + "&sort=price&type="+ type +"&apikey=21f2ed18-88b1-5d26-34f3-28318713eaf4");

        Log.e(TAG, "Response from url: " + jsonStr);

        if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                // Getting JSON Array node
                JSONArray contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray("stations");

                // looping through All Contacts
                for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {

                    JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

                    String id = c.getString("id");
                    String price = c.getString("price");

                    //tmp hash map for single contact
                    HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    contact.put("id",id);
                    contact.put("price", price);

                    //adding contact to contact list
                    contactList.add(contact);
                    }

                }

            } catch (final JSONException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                    }
                });
            }
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't get json from server.");
            getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                }
            });
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute (Void result){
        super.onPostExecute(result);     
        /**
         * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
         * */
        mContactsAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                getActivity(), mContactListItems,
                R.layout.list_item, new String[]{"price", "brand",
                "dist", "street", "houseNumber", "postcode", "place"}, new int[]{R.id.stoff,
                R.id.brand, R.id.dist, R.id.street, R.id.houseNumber, R.id.postCode, R.id.place});

mContactListItems.addAll(contactListTwo);
mContactsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        rg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                mContactsListItems.clear();

                switch (checkedId) {
                    case R.id.radioButton4:
                        mContactsListItems.addAll(contactList);
                        break;
                    case R.id.radioButton5:
                        mContactsListItems.addAll(contactListTwo);
                        break;                       
                }
                //mark as changed, update list
                mContactsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        });

 }
}
```

Comment: You are setting view ids in xml and then overriding them in code? Also view id needs to be a "positive number".

Comment: What do you mean with view ids? I‘m using it in a fragment by the way!

Comment: I was referring  to this `rb1.setId(rb1id);` Refer to [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setId(int))

Comment: Ah okay. Well the ids are set at the top

Comment: You are comparing ids set in code with ids set in xml, that would not work.

Comment: Ah now I get it. For me it actually works, but how would you improve it? Would it help me with my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing one list object to your adapter (`contactListTwo`), but updating a different list object in your checked change listener (`mContactsListItems`). This means that your changes are totally invisible to your adapter.

To fix, change the list reference you pass to the adapter's constructor:

```
new SimpleAdapter(..., mContactsListItems, ...);
```

I notice that you never set the initial items to this list, so you may also have to call e.g. `mContactsListItems.addAll(contactListTwo)` before you create the adapter for the first time. That just depends on whether or not you want the list to be empty before the user changes the radio buttons.

## Edit

There's a second problem: the way you assign your adapter to the `ListView`. In your `onCreate()`, I see this line:

> ```
> ((ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list))
>         .setAdapter(mContactsAdapter);
> ```

At the point where this code runs, I don't see any initialization of `mContactsAdapter`, so unless you've omitted that code, this is going to be the same as writing `setAdapter(null)`.

Later on, in `onPostExecute()`, you create a `new` adapter and assign it to `mContactsAdapter`. However, this doesn't actually affect the list view! You need to re-set the adapter if you re-assign its variable.

So you either have to initialize the adapter before you set it on your list view in `onCreate()` (which is fine to do even though you haven't loaded the data yet; the adapter will just be empty), or you have to call `setAdapter()` again in your `onPostExecute()` method to assign this new adapter to your list view.

Comment: That‘s a good suggestion, thank you! But unfortunately it doesn’t show up in my listView. I also print them in my logcat and I see that everything seems to work, but for some reason the space where the listView should be stays blank. Do you have an idea what could be wrong there?

Comment: @MikeKng I've updated my answer to cover what I think you're seeing

Comment: Awesome, that really was the problem. This works for the code I set as the inital item. When i click the radiobuttons, it gets cleared as it should, but nothing new is loaded in. Do you have a hint why it‘s not loaded into the mContactsListItems as well?

Comment: I found a solution for that, thank you very much for your help!